# How to move a paragraph and paste it without an initial newline first

Tags: cut-copy-paste

If I have a pair of quotes on a line by themselves:

```
''
```

...and a short paragraph of text, say three lines of text:

```
some text
that I'd like 
to move
```

Now if I want to move the text into the quotes, I can place the caret at the line above the first line of text and press <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to select and delete them - but how can I paste them in between the quotes in the easiest way possible? The problem is that pasting them will add them on the line *below* the quotes, producing this result:

```
''
some text
that I'd like 
to move
```

Until now I've typically done something like entering a newline between the quotes, then pasting the text between them, resulting in something like this...

```
'
some text
that I'd like 
to move
'
```

...after which I'd remove the newlines at the top and bottom using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. This works, but it feels clumsy.

Is there a better way?

Just to be clear, this is the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
'some text
that I'd like 
to move'
```

Comment: My initial thought was to use `:help o_v` for this, but when I tried to formulate a solution I kept getting thwarted by the exceptions described in `:help exclusive`. I'd be interested to know if there *are* any solutions using `o_v` that I just missed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you paste the contents of a register in insert mode, you don't have the initial newline.

For instance, we have this text:

```
''
some text
that I'd like
to move
```

Place your caret on the beginning of the second line in normal mode and type <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>:

- <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>: cut the three following lines;
- <kbd>a</kbd>: go to insert mode after the selected character;
- <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>: paste the content of the default register (directly after the caret, so without the newline);
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd>: remove the last newline.

You get:

```
'some text
that I'd like
to move'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help! I guess I'll have to look more into the details of using registers. :)

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to create [:h characterwise-register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#characterwise-register) to paste into `''`.

place your cursor any place in the paragraph and do:

```
vipv$hd
```

move to first `'`

```
p
```

done.

- `vip` select paragraph, [:h ip](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#ip) is linewise, which means current visual mode is `V`.
- `v`   change mode to `v`, which is `character wise`, check [:h v_v](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#v_v) if you have doubt.
- `$h` select until last character of last line, `h` is used to exclude trailing linebreak.
- `d`  delete into to register.

**Update**

@Rich mentioned `v}ged` in the comment, it's 2 characters shorter, it doesn't involve count, although you must place cursor at start of the paragraph, it's still a very intuitive and handy method.

Comment: I like it. I'd do `V2jvg_d` instead, but for the most part same idea. Actually, this also works: `v3g_d`, two characters shorter (for the Vimgolfer in me...)

Comment: @filbranden It's good to know `g_`, i have never used it. `v3g_d` is shorter, but it involves a count, count is bad.

Comment: If we're golfing (but also trying to avoid counts), how about `v}ged`?

Comment: @Rich `ge` is another useful command I barely used, although it still involves place cursor at the start of the paragraph, I believe it's an useful style.